# How do I correctly nest a <frameset>?

Tags: html

When I try to nest a frameset inside another frameset, it does not work.

I have tried using  tag but it did not go that well.

```
<frameset rows="15%,85%">
    <frame style="background-color: orangered"></frame>
    <frame style="background-color: saddlebrown">
        <frameset cols="20%,*">
            <frame style="background-color: teal">
                <frameset rows="50%,*">
                    <frame style="background-color: violet"></frame>
                </frameset>
            </frame>
        </frameset>
    </frame>

</frameset>
```

I expect it to divide another frame that has already been divided.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a paper and a pen first ! draw a box. Take another color pen and divide. put names inside the boxesNote a count number on the divider line. Divide one of the two new boxes. maybee use another pen and for sure also note a counter note also the names inside the boxes. That is how framesets work. take al oook at https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>A simple frameset document</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<FRAMESET cols="20%, 80%"> <!--(1)-->
     <FRAMESET rows="100, 200"> <!--(2)-->
       <FRAME src="contents_of_frame1.html">
       <FRAME src="contents_of_frame2.gif">
    </FRAMESET>

    <FRAME src="contents_of_frame3.html">


  <!-- optional for browser which do not know frameset or blind peoples with text 
       readers as well as very dumb search engines -->

  <NOFRAMES>
      <P>This frameset document contains:
     <UL>
        <LI><A href="contents_of_frame1.html">Some neat contents</A>
        <LI><IMG src="contents_of_frame2.gif" alt="A neat image">
        <LI><A href="contents_of_frame3.html">Some other neat contents</A>
  </UL>
  </NOFRAMES>
  <--  end optional     -->


</FRAMESET>
```

that might create a frame layout something like this:

```
      ---------------------------------------
      |         |                             |
      |         |                             |
      | Frame 1 |                             |
      |         |                             |
      |         |                             |
      |----(2)--|                             |
      |         |          Frame 3            |
      |         |                             |
      |        (1)                            |
      |         |                             |
      | Frame 2 |                             |
      |         |                             |
      |         |                             |
      |         |                             |
      |         |                             |
       ---------------------------------------
```